# Reset Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto

I'm creating a map like this:

```js
var map_object = new L.Map('map', {
    center: [39.8282, -98.5795],
    zoom: 5,

});

var sublayers = [];

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
}).addTo(map_object);

cartodb.createLayer(map_object,layerSource,options)
    .addTo(map_object)
    .done(function(layer) {
       for (var i = 0; i < layer.getSubLayerCount(); i++) {
           sublayers[i] = layer.getSubLayer(i);               
       }
    })
```

This works great. I'm then changing the zoom and adding circles based on user clicking buttons.

Is there a simple way to get the map back to its original condition (i.e. before all the changes and additions created by user actions)? I'm looking to see if there's something better than removing each layer and rezooming, etc.

I tried to use `map.remove` and then run all the code above again, but this gives me an error:

> Uncaught Error: Map container not found.

Which is referring to this line:

```js
var map_object = new L.Map('map', {
```

Comment: Sounds like Leaflet can't find the map div. Is it possible that you've deleted the div from the dom, using something like jQuery remove()? `$( "#map" ).remove();`

Comment: I thought this was the issue as well, but I've got nothing like this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sublayer.remove()`([docs](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayerremove)) or `sublayer.hide()` ([docs](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayerhide)) when the reset button is clicked.

[This course](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-2.html) of the CartoDB Academy explains how to work with .show() and .hide() in an interactive map via Javascript.

A related code sample:

```
var sublayer0Shown = true;
$("#sublayer0").on('click', function() {
    if (sublayer0Shown) {
        sublayers[0].hide();
    } else {
        sublayers[0].show();
    }
    sublayer0Shown = !sublayer0Shown; 
});
```